# Компиляция LWJGL.dll 2.9.4

Tags: c, dll, компиляция, jni, lwjgl

Всем доброе время суток. Хотелось бы немного изменить нативный код LWJGL 2.9.4 версии. К сожалению, долго искал, но так и не нашёл исходного кода этой версии. Обнаружил только 2.9.3, но даже с ней не могу разобраться, как компилировать. Использую VS Studio 2019. Создал С++ проект .dll, подключил JNI, из скачанного архива вытянуть заголовочные файлы из папок common и windows, подключил. Вытянул .c файлы и добавил в исходный код - получил около 59+ ошибок, притом некоторые из них связаны с дубликатом файлов и методов внутри. Есть ли у кого информация, как правильно откомпилировать этот код? Исходники 2.9.3 я нашёл здесь: https://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.9.3/lwjgl-source-2.9.3.zip/download.
Сразу скажу, я программирую в основном на Java, Си и С++ не знаю, но хотелось бы поковыряться в нём. По этому и прошу помощи

Comment: *"Си и С++ не знаю"* - ну так сначала узнайте, а потом беритесь собирать сложные кросс-языковые проекты.

Comment: На [git-е проекта](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl) сказано компилировать через `Ant`.